# apply a function in a data frame based on values from another data frame

Tags: r

I have these two data.frames

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), V2=c(0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9))
  V1  V2
1  A 0.8
2  A 0.2
3  B 0.3
4  B 0.4
5  B 0.9

df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B"), V2=c(0.3, 0.8))

  V1  V2
1  A 0.3
2  B 0.8
```

I would like add a new column to df1, `df$v3` based on V1 names and on the values of df2,i.e, `if (df1$V1 < df2$V2) {df$V3 == -1, else df$V3 == 0}`. For illustration the desired output for the example will be the following:

```
  V1  V2 V3
1  A 0.8  0
2  A 0.2 -1
3  B 0.3 -1
4  B 0.4 -1
5  B 0.9  0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there are some typos in your example data and expected output. Regardless, perhaps you want to `merge` the data frames (rename `V2` in `df2` first) and then use `ifelse`.

Comment: Thanks @joran, I have edited my post, and think your approach will work perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I outlined in my comment, I think this is sort of what you're after:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), V2=c(0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B"), V2a=c(0.3, 0.8))
df <- merge(df1,df2)
df$V3 <- with(df,ifelse(V2 < V2a,-1,0))
> df
  V1  V2 V2a V3
1  A 0.8 0.3  0
2  A 0.2 0.3 -1
3  B 0.3 0.8 -1
4  B 0.4 0.8 -1
5  B 0.9 0.8  0
```

As I mentioned, I changed one of the columns names in `df2` to make the merging work properly.

Comment: you don't need to change the name, just use the `by` argument of `merge`

Comment: @eddi I know I don't need to, but for some reason it seemed easier that way when I was writing my answer.